# How to convert TEXT data type value to DATE data type value in UPDATE statement in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I tried to UPDATE 2 columns by converting TEXT data type to DATE data type value using PostgreSQL but I'm getting this error:

Here is my error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "CAST"
LINE 2: SET   CAST(sle.log_field1 as DATE),
              ^
********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near "CAST"
SQL state: 42601
Character: 41
```

Here is my code:

```
UPDATE      student_log_entries sle
SET         CAST(sle.log_field1 as DATE),
        CAST(sle.log_field3 as DATE)
WHERE       sle.student_field_id = 400010960;
```

Any help/direction to accomplish this would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: You need to `ALTER` the table if you want to change the data type.

Comment: The relevant syntax is: `UPDATE tbl SET col = expr;` The question is missing the target column(s) (what @Patrick put in an answer, I see it now)

Answer (score 3):

You need to include column names in your `UPDATE` statement:

```
UPDATE      student_log_entries sle
SET <name of a column> = CAST(sle.log_field1 as DATE),
    <name of a column> = CAST(sle.log_field3 as DATE)
WHERE       sle.student_field_id = 400010960;
```

Comment: Patrick - thank you.  That was stupid on my part.  I appreciate the reply and your help.

Comment: We all have our moments of temporary blindness. Good luck with your database.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the column has not been updated, following query will change the field type to `date` via a `USING` clause.

```
ALTER TABLE student_log_entries 
   ALTER COLUMN log_field3 TYPE date 
   USING to_date(log_field3, 'YYYY-MM-DD');
```

If you need you can use any custom function to cast instead of to_date after `USING` keyword.

If already altered the column, Patrick's answer will do it.

Comment: The table has been ALTERED however I'm needing to UPDATE records that were entered incorrectly from the front-end application.  Is there not a way to do that using PostgreSQL?  Thanks.

Comment: @TobySpeight Edited. :)